# Is there a way to resume an interrupted scp of a file?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, scp

I'm occasionally downloading a very large file via scp and there's a small chance each time of the connection dropping and cutting the transfer mid-way.

Is there a way to resume it?

Comment: Check `ulimit -a | grep 'file size'` when it's failing with `File too large`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try the following approch: instead of *scp* use *dd* to skip over the downloaded part and append the remainder to the file.

```
sofar=`ls -l ./destfile | awk '{print $5}'`
ssh user@host "dd if=./srcfile bs=1 skip=$sofar" >> ./destfile
```

Possible optimization: work with big blocks. Let's leave this as a homework.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but am accepting the answer tentatively since using dd sounds like a great approach for solution.

Comment: I just tested it, works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Kossak, nice to hear!

Comment: `dd` with small blocksizes can be slow (just 350 kB/s here). Fortunately, `scp` transfers seem to come in 1024 byte blocks. If so for your file (or else, by truncating it to the closest 1024 byte block), you can speed it up like this: `ssh rsys "dd if=./srcfile bs=1024 skip=$sofar" >> ./destfile`. (Note that `$sofar` then has to be the number of 1024 byte blocks to skip!)

Comment: It took me some time to realize that `rsys` in the second line is just an example hostname not some special argument for `ssh`. I suggest you replace it with `user@host` to avoid confusion.

Comment: To increase blocksize, find a factor of $sofar close to 1000, and set bs (blocksize) to it. And divide $sofar by bs.

Answer (score 39):

With `scp`, no.

If both ends have it, you can use `rsync -LvzP remoteserver:path/to/file localfile` to transfer a single file.

Comment: This saved me hours of downloading a huge file which got interrupted. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting following error while using this command
"X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

Comment: 10 years later and you just saved me 6 hours

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are ways to resume from the point of interruption, but it is not possible using scp. `sftp reget filename` does what you need.  Yarek and Grawity have provided valid solutions that I +1 to both, but for resuming from a point of interruption, I like rsync.  The example commands provided both assume you are retrieving a file from a remote server to your local workstation (downloading).  Please keep in mind that the final two parameters should be considered source_file and target_file in that order.  The syntax of the filename varies based on whether the source or target file is local or remote.  If I were sending (uploading) [text] files, I would rewrite the examples provided as:

```
#From local to remote
sofar=`ssh remote_system ls -l interrupted_file | awk '{print $5}'`;
dd if=source_file bs=1 skip=$sofar | ssh remote_system "cat >> ./interrupted_file"
```

And to the rsync solution, I add `-e ssh`. You should consider whether or not you need verbosity, compression, preserve ownership, permissions, timestamp, recurse directories, etc.  Check man pages and google, regarding the -L parameter.  You might want symlinks to remain as links instead of referencing them.

`rsync -P -e ssh local_source_file remoteserver:path/to/interrupted_target_file`

Answer (score 7):

There's another solution (besides the `rsync` or `dd` solutions stated here) which I'm surprised nobody mentioned: it's the `reput` command of `sftp`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if both ends support sftp - after `scp remoteuser@remotehost:/absolute/filename .` fails you can resume by doing `sftp remoteuser@remotehost` and then `reget /absolute/filename` to resume the download.

Answer (score 2):

```
scp -o ConnectTimeout 60
```

Lets you specify the timeout for a connection. May keep your connection from breaking up.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of yrk does work if you are copying from a remote to a local machine. If in your case you are trying to run `scp -3` between two remotes that cannot communicate directly to eachother you can use the following solution.
Assume 'source_file' is located on 'host_source' and 'dest_file' is located on 'host_dest'.

1. ssh into host_dest and check the current file size

   ls -l dest_file | awk '{print $5}'

   Write down the output, e.g. 7544684
2. From your local machine:

   ssh user@host_source "dd if=source_file bs=1 skip=7544684" | ssh user@host_dest -T "cat >> dest_file"

Comment: Nice tips! but I think there is no need to add '-T' option, AFAIK ssh doesn't allocate a pseudo tty if you specify a command for it. see https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2013/05/forcing-pseudo-terminal-on-ssh-command.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

`scp -o ConnectTimeout=60`

instead of:

`scp -o ConnectTimeout 60`